# JavaScript - Why does split using RegEx produce blank array?

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I am working on a RegEx problem and I just encountered some unexpected behaviour.
If I [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the word "Hello" by word cherters (`\w`) I get and array of empty strings:

```
"Hello".split(/\w/)

Array(6) [ "", "", "", "", "", "" ]
```

I would expect H e l l o.
Why does this happen?
What RegEx can I use to create the desired result?

## Edit

The full reason why I want to use RegEx is because I have a string containing Emoji, so `Hello`  for eg, I want to split the string but keep the emoji (Unicode) intack.
I should of explained this to start with.

**Thank you all** for your help, after I realised the difference between `match` and `split` it didn't take me long to sort the Emoji issue either:

```
"Hello ".match(/(\w)|([^\u0000-\u007F]+)/g)

Array(6) [ "H", "e", "l", "l", "o", "" ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing `split` (matching delimiter), with `match` (matching content). With `split` you identify what *separates* the actual content, so the matches themselves will be excluded. With `match` you get what you were actually looking for. Note that with `match` you need to explicitly say you want all of them, using the `g` modifier:

```js
let arr = "Hello".match(/\w/g); // You need the g[lobal] modifier
console.log(arr); // ["H","e","l","l","o"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regex for that, you can split on an empty string to get the characters:

```js
var result = "Hello".split("")

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I should of explained the full reason why I want to do this. I have a string containing Emoji like `Hello `, I want to split the string but keep the Emoji intact. So I imagined `\w` word characters would do the job.

Answer (score 1):

It takes exactly what you did. The value to look for splitting is a word character and you get exact the empty space between all characters.

```js
console.log("Hello".split(/\w/));
```

To get what you want is either to use `match`

```js
console.log("Hello".match(/\w/g));
console.log("Hello world!".match(/\w/g));
```

or split by the space between, an empty string.

```js
console.log("Hello".split(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get an empty array it's because `split()`'s first parameter searches for a pattern and the pattern in this case is a character and split is dividing the word `Hello` by each character, and that's why you get the empty strings
to achieve what you want use split("")

```js
var res = "Hello".split("")
console.log(res)
```